# SBT: How to ensure that local snapshot dependency is picked up?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have 2 scala projects, A and B. A has dependency on B. I have to do some local testing before pushing changes to central remote repo. So I make changes in B,change its version.sbt to 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and publish it locally using

```
sbt publishLocal
```

I can see 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT saved in in 'C:\var.ivy2\local'.

In A, I change DependencyManagement.scala to now pick up snapshot version of B:

```
val BVersion = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

But during debugging A, I see that B's classes are picked up from jars in: `C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\....\artifactory\virtual-ivy`

How can I ensure that snapshot version is picked?

Comment: Use a different version that is only published in your local repository?

Comment: Just to be sure, your SBT `repositories` file contains `local` repo?

Comment: @luis But i am already doing that..isnt?i have put 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT in B's version.sbt, and then used this version in A.

Comment: @Mandroid then I do not understand what is the question? Isn't the path you show a local one? Did you reloaded the sbt shell?

Comment: OP is saying that artifact is resolved from Coursier cache of a remote repository rather than its personal local repository

Answer (score 5):

Try setting coursier [TTL](https://get-coursier.io/docs/ttl) to 0 seconds in `build.sbt`

```
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt
import lmcoursier.definitions.CachePolicy

csrConfiguration := csrConfiguration.value
  .withTtl(0.seconds)
  .withCachePolicies(Vector(CachePolicy.LocalOnly)
```

or via environmental variable

```
COURSIER_TTL="0s"
```

as per sbt [docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Dependency-Management-Flow.html#Notes+on+SNAPSHOTs)

> By default, `SNAPSHOT` artifacts in Coursier are given 24h
> time-to-live (TTL) to avoid network IO. If you need to force
> re-resolution of `SNAPSHOTS`, run sbt with `COURSIER_TTL` environment
> variable set to `0s`

Comment: So this change is to be made in B's build.sbt? And what exactly would it do? Would it publish snapshot to coursier cache?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to publish locally to test your changes. You can also add a local subproject dependency using `ProjectRef`:

```
lazy val B = ProjectRef(file("path/to/B"), "nameOfSubproject")
lazy val A = (project in file("A")).dependsOn(B)
```

That's actually more convenient as sbt is going to recompile B automatically when needed.

Comment: IntelliJ may have added the second line for you when creating the project. In my case, the resulting line looks like this: `lazy val \`myproject\` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).dependsOn(B)`

Comment: Is this also possible somehow with sub modules of another project? It seem to require a `project` folder and fails the build with `Invalid build URI (no handler available)`

Comment: My example shows how to do it for a subproject.